# JavaScript Confirmation form Message

Tags: javascript

I have a confirmation message in my form with JS script but the value of "verif" always false or I do not know where is the problem; If I boot "verif" with false, it's still false

```
    function valider() {
    var verif = false;
    swal({
        title: "Are you sure?",
        text: "You will not be able to recover       this  file!",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
        confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
        cancelButtonText: "No, cancel plx!",
        closeOnConfirm: false,
        closeOnCancel: false
    }, function(isConfirm) {
        if (isConfirm) {
            swal("Deleted!", "Your  file has been deleted.", "success");
            verif = true;
            alert("afficher");
        } else {
            swal("Cancelled", "Your  file is safe :)", "error");
            verif = false;
            swal("afficher");
        }
    });

    if (verif) {
        $("#formulaire").submit();
    }

    return false;
}



$("#envoyer").click(function() {
    valider();
    return false;
});
```

and this is the HTML Code

```
<form action="archi.php" method="post" class="form-horizontal"     id="formulaire">

<div class="form-actions">
<button type="submit" id="envoyer" class="btn blue envoyer">  <i    class="icon-save"></i> Archiver</button>
<button type="button" class="btn">Cancel</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you add another test for submitting? Add submit to the callback function and delete additional `if`:

```
function valider() {
    var verif = false;
    swal({
        title: "Are you sure?",
        text: "You will not be able to recover       this  file!",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
        confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
        cancelButtonText: "No, cancel plx!",
        closeOnConfirm: false,
        closeOnCancel: false
    }, function(isConfirm) {
        if (isConfirm) {
            $("#formulaire").submit();  
            swal("Deleted!", "Your  file has been deleted.", "success");
        } else {
            swal("Cancelled", "Your  file is safe :)", "error");
            swal("afficher");
        }
    });

    return false;
}



$("#envoyer").click(function() {
    valider();
    return false;
});
```

**P.S.** Try adding a `console.log()` before the return from `verif()` function to check if the `}, function(isConfirm) {` is async (this would clarify all misunderstanding).